# Why isn’t implicit type conversion happening from unsigned short int to signed char?

Tags: c, type-conversion, char, short

code 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    short int a = -1; // ----> Line 1
    unsigned int b = 122; // ----> Line 2
    
    if (a > b)
        printf("a is big");
    else
        printf("a is small");

    return 0;
}
```

Output: `a is big`

Since here the Line 1 is implicitly converted to Line 2, ie: `signed short int` to `unsigned int`.

similarly

code 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a = -1; // ---> Line 3
    unsigned short int b = 122; // ---> Line 4
    
    if (a > b)
        printf("a is big");
    else
        printf("a is small");

    return 0;
}
```

Output: `a is small`

Here in code 2, since `unsigned short int` (Line 4) is greater than `signed char` (Line 3), why is the implicit conversion not happening?

or

Why doesn't the implicit conversion for `unsigned short int` and `signed char` take place?

Comment: In the second snippet both `-1` and `122` are converted into `int` before the comparison and are keeping their values, because they can fit. In the first snippet both are compared as `unsigned int`, so `-1` has to be converted to it and become a large value. Relevant rules are listed under the [usual arithmetic conversions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.8)

Answer (score 2):

This little riddle hides a difficult problem: integer promotions may behave differently on different systems, depending on the size of types `char`, `short` and `int`.

When an operation is evaluated between types that have a rank lesser or equal to that of `int`, *integer promotions* are performed and the operation is evaluated on the resulting type, `int` or `unsigned int` depending on the original types.

If both types are smaller (have fewer value bits) than `int`, they are promoted to `int`, which preserves the value.  If one or both have the same number of value bits as `unsigned int`, they are both promoted to `unsigned int`, which changes negative values to large positive ones.

In addition to this difficulty, you are storing the value `-1` to a variable of type `char`.  Depending on the signedness of type `char`, the value `-1` may be converted to the positive value `UCHAR_MAX`.  This is the case if type `char` is unsigned.

Let's investigate your examples:

code 1:

```
short int a = -1; // ----> Line 1
unsigned int b = 122; // ----> Line 2
```

`short int` `a` is promoted to `unsigned int`, the type of `b` and the value `-1` changes to `UINT_MAX`, which is much larger than `122`, hence the comparison is true, `a is big`. This behavior does not depend on the architecture.

code 2:

```
char a = -1; // ---> Line 3
unsigned short int b = 122; // ---> Line 4
```

- if `char` is signed, `a` has the value `-1`, but if `char` is unsigned, `a` would have the value `UCHAR_MAX`, which is `255` on architectures with 8-bit bytes.
- if type `unsigned short int` has the same size as `unsigned int` (16-bit architectures), both values are promoted to `unsigned int` (`-1` becomes `UINT_MAX`) and the comparison is either `UINT_MAX > 122` or `255 > 122`, which is true in both cases.
- if type `unsigned short int` is smaller than `int`, both values are promoted to `int` and the comparison is either `-1 > 122` or `255 > 122`, which depends on the signedness of type `char`.

Your system outputs `a is small`, which means `char` is signed and `short` has fewer bits than `int`, so the comparison is `-1 > 122`, which is false.

Answer (score 1):

`char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`, `short`, and `unsigned short` are never considered as result types of the integer promotions.

The integer promotions originated in early C development where arithmetic was largely done using the native processor registers in their ordinary widths, and `char` and `short` were types used for storing data. The `int` type was used as the “natural” type on the processor, matching its registers. So `char` and `short` data was loaded into processor registers and then operated on with, in effect, instructions that performed `int` arithmetic. The current rules of standard C reflect this history; the *integer promotions* bring integer types up to at least `int` or `unsigned int`.

In your C implementation, `unsigned short int` is narrower than `int`, so it is promoted to `int`. So is `char`. Thus the `char` value −1 is promoted to `int`, yielding an `int` value of −1, and the `unsigned short int` value of 122 is promoted to `int`, yielding an `int` value of 122, and these are compared. Then −1 is not greater than 122, so `a > b` evaluates as false.

The specific rules for the *usual arithmetic conversions* are:

- If either operand (or, if complex, its corresponding real type) is `long double`, the other operand is converted to `long double`.
- Otherwise, if either operand (or, if complex, its corresponding real type) is `double`, the other operand is converted to `double`.
- Otherwise, if either operand (or, if complex, its corresponding real type) is `float`, the other operand is converted to `float`.
- Otherwise, the *integer promotions* are performed on both operands: A value with a type with integer conversion rank less than `int` is converted to `int` if `int` can represent all values of the source type (for example, if `unsigned short` is the same width as `int`, it has some values that `int` cannot represent) or to `unsigned int` otherwise. (Values with a type with greater rank are not converted.) Values with bit-field types of `_Bool`, `int` or `unsigned int` are also converted in this way.
- If both resulting operands have the same type, no further conversion is performed.
- Otherwise, if both have signed type or both have unsigned type, the operand with lower rank is converted to the other type.
- Otherwise, if rank of the unsigned type is at least the rank of the signed type, the signed type is converted to the unsigned type.
- Otherwise, if the signed type can represent all the values of the unsigned type, the unsigned type is converted to the signed type.
- Otherwise, both operands are converted to the unsigned type corresponding to the signed type. (For example, if the operands are `unsigned short` and `int`, and those have the same width, they will be converted to `unsigned int`.)